# Async function returns [object Object] instead of value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

In calling an async function, I am expecting it to return a JSON payload so I can extract a value from the object. However, the function only returns `[object Object]`

The async function was being called in a normal function, so I tried changing the parent function to an async function. This helped me because originally I was only getting a value of `[object Promise]`

Originally, I was attempting this:

```
const sendRequestToApprover = (userId, announcement, username) => {
  const { title, details, channel } = announcement;

  const channelName = channels.getChannelName(channel);
  console.log('channelName' + channelName);
```

and `getChannelName` looks like:

```
async function getChannelName(id) { 
  try {
    return await api.get('/channels.info', {
      params: { 
        token: botToken,
        channel: id,
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I was able to resolve the issue of getting `[object Promise]` by making the following change to `sendRequestToApprover`:

```
async function sendRequestToApprover(userId, announcement, username) {
  const { title, details, channel } = announcement;

  const channelName = await channels.getChannelName(channel);

  console.log('channelName' + channelName);
```

Note it is now an async function and I added `await` to the function call.

I know the payload called by will return the following:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "channel": {
        "id": "CJSFDR83T",
        "name": "general",
...
}
```

I can't quite figure out why I can't get to the name in this case. I've done this in other functions and this one has me stumped. `channelName` is still returning `[object Object]`.

Comment: `console.log('channelName' + channelName)` will implicitly convert `channelName` to a string

Comment: use   console.log('channelName' + channelName.channel.name);

Comment: You are logging the complete object returned by function, its value isn't [object object], its getting converted to string at console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel pretty defeated after trying to figure this out this weekend.

I figured this out by assigning the API call to a variable and logging the result.

```
try {
    const result = await api.get('/channels.info', {
      params: { 
        token: botToken,
        channel: id,
      }
    });
```

Then I tried logging `result` and saw the payload! So I updated the function as so:

```
async function getChannelName(id) { 
  try {
    const result = await api.get('/channels.info', {
      params: { 
        token: botToken,
        channel: id,
      }
    });
    return result.data.channel.name
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Now my `channelName` variable returns the channel name!

Comment: You should now understand enough to make your first attempt work. ie do the `result.data.channel.name` bit in the caller after awaiting `channels.getChannelName(channel)`.

Comment: There are circumstances where you might choose to catch errors - for example to inject a default value after a failure, or to set a custom error message ... but here, suggest not to catch. As written, if the catch clause runs, the returned promise will resolve to `undefined`. A caught error stays caught and the caller is not informed of it unless it is re-thrown. You can always log the error from the caller (or the caller's caller etc) if need be.

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing this:

```
console.log("channelName" + channelName);
```

You're calling the `toString` method on `channelName`, and on an object this results in `[object Object]`.

```js
console.log("Object.toString() -> " + { foo: "bar" });
```

You can avoid this by passing another argument to `console.log`.

```js
console.log("Object.toString() -> ", { foo: "bar" });
```

Comment: Some of the articles I found mentioned using `toString()` but I couldn't figure out how to implement it. Your answer provides a little more clarity. I answered my own question. Check out my answer and let me know what you think.